# isomorophic-fetch don't post json body

Tags: json, post, reactjs, fetch, isomorphic-fetch-api

I have this code in my react app  and it didn't post the json body !
have tried every solution even the one here https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/34 not working too , i can do the post with jquery , but i need to use fetch , any idea ?

```
fetch('/main/newuser',{
            method:'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({username:'test',password:'test'})
        }).then((response)=>{
            if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300){
                return response;
            }else{
                var error = new Error(response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        }).then((response)=>{
            return response.json();
        }).then((data)=>{
            /* Process data */
        }).catch((error)=>{
            /* Catch Error */
        });
```

Comment: What is a response from the server?

Comment: When using your code on a fake API it works. I can't reproduce the issue. Are you sure your API is working correctly? http://jsbin.com/foyanir/edit?js,console

Comment: The server can't get the json body , when use jquery it works well , so the server code is ok ,

Comment: Have you tried using a different fetch polyfill? e.g. the one from Github https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: isomorophic-fetch is built on fetch polyfill , you think may solve the problem ? anyway will try it now

Comment: tried it with no luck too

Comment: Could you give us the error in the console? Response from the server?

Comment: there is no error , the server check and validate the data and then response as data is ok or not , and it response as user name is required , password is required etc , when check the log of the server it get nothing in the body just the header of the request , when check the request header and body from developer tools , i see empty body

Comment: the server get the header and empty body and response with status code 200 and message ( username is required .. etc  )

Comment: Also i diabled all the data check on the server ( even it work with jquery ) and just logged the input post data , and as expected empty data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After tried everything possible ( edit code as sugguested , check the browser up to date and working , check the server code , the library work will with the GET method but POST still not working ) i switched back to our old and love JQuery !